# Visual Studio 2012 doesn't build C# project when C++ dependency changes

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have three projects in my solution: a C++ project called LibX, a C# project called LibX.NET which wraps LibX.dll using P/Invoke, and a C# WPF app called TestX.

LibX.NET is marked as dependent on LibX, and TestX copies LibX.dll to its output directory as part of a post-build step (since I can't think of a better way to ensure that TestX can use LibX.dll).

In VS2010, when I change a file in LibX and build, both LibX.NET and TestX are built, and so their post-build event fires and everything is made up-to-date.

However, in VS2012, when I change a file in LibX, VS doesn't build LibX.NET and TestX, claiming that they are "up-to-date". Is this a bug/regression in VS2012, or is it intentional? How do I get TestX to run its post-build step?

Answer (score 0):

If you want changes in LibX to trigger builds in LibX.Net you need to reverse your project dependency between these two projects.

Since you have marked LibX.Net depends on LibX then you will need to compile LiX.Net to get both projects built. When you do that both projects will get compiled/skipped based on whether changes were made. And this is the same behavior in VS2010.

Comment: So, I should make the C++ project LibX depend on the C# project LibX.NET? I'm not sure I follow the logic...

Comment: I am not saying you should but based on what you are expecting you would have to. Think of the dependency as an external project dependency.

Comment: The behaviour has clearly changed in VS2012...ah well. My current solution is just to mandate that we develop in VS2010, which I suppose we were going to do anyway to avoid the solution upgrade treadmill.

Comment: VS2010 and VS2012 support roudrtripping so there is minimal overhead in terms of moving on the client. I just tried out your exact same scenario and it works the same between the two releases so if you find there be an issue I suggest you should file a connect bug.